# 500 internal server error con el paquete laravel WEBSOCKETS

Tags: laravel, websocket, vps

Con ayuda del paquete laravel-websockets https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction instalé mi propio VPS (virtual private server) el cual está funcionando bien la mayor parte del tiempo, sin embargo, inexplicablemente en distintas horas del día, el servidor deja de funcionar, presentando un error 500 (internal server error) y luego de unos minutos, el servidor vuelve a funcionar normalmente. ¿Qué está sucediendo?

Tengo la impresión de que se debe a la cantidad de peticiones que recibe, pero ¿Cómo puedo monitorear la cantidad de peticiones por segundo que recibe el servidor?

Gracias

El trazo del error es el siguiente:

> [2020-05-27 17:49:45] production.ERROR: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(c$ [stacktrace] #0 /var/www/pusher/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('PRAGMA foreign_.$ #1 /var/www/pusher/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(465): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('PRAGMA foreign_...', Array, O$ #2

Comment: 500 (internal server error) es un mensaje genérico. Revisa en los logs de laravel lo que dice el trazo del error para tener algo más específico

Comment: [2020-05-27 17:49:45] production.ERROR: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(c$
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/pusher/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(631): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('PRAGMA foreign_.$
#1 /var/www/pusher/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(465): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('PRAGMA foreign_...', Array, O$
#2

Comment: `could not find driver`<-- te falta dejar el driver de conexión a la BD (la librería JDBC, por ejemplo) donde PHP la está buscando.

Comment: El paquete de laravel websockets funciona con o sin base de datos correctamente. ¿Piensas que ese driver podría estar generando el intermitente error 500?